# Double coset decomposition

Tags: group-theory

I came across the following nice isomorphism: consider $G$ a group and let $H, K$ two subgroups then
\begin{equation} 
G/H\times G/K \cong \coprod_{H\backslash G/H}G/(H^g\cap K).
\end{equation}
Unfortunately I could not find the proof. I tried to write it down on my own but I have some problem. My first idea was to simply write down two explicit maps which are inverses, but I cannot do that.

From the LHS to the RHS: we start a pair of cosets $(aH, bK)$ and clearly the want to sent it to the component indexed by the double coset $Ha^{-1}bK$, but what should be the coset with respect to $H^{a^{-1}b}\cap K$ individuated by the pair? My problem is that I cannot come up with a formula using $aH$ and $bK$ which well defined.

If I want to define a map in the opposite direction my bet would be sending $xH^{g}\cap K$ to $(gxg^{-1}H, xK)$: it is easy to verify that it does not depend on the choice of the representative $x$ but I cannot prove the same for the representative $g$ of the double coset $HgK$.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had made it clearer what  exactly this is an isomorphism of. It is an isomorphism of left $G$-actions (or $G$-sets), where both actions are defined by left multiplication.

Comment: Actually, I was not sure myself. The notes where I found this claim just stated "isomorphism" as bijection of sets. But it is now clear that you want to get an isomorphism of $G$-sets.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that the answer was no so abstruse after all. After I realized that the isomorphism is supposed to be $G$-equivariant and the orbit-stabilizer would be helpful the solution presented itself.

We start by considering $G/H\times G/K$ with the diagonal $G$-action. We first want to understand the orbits: one orbit is in the form $G.(xH, yK)$ and it is immediate that taken any of its elements $(gxH, gyK)$ the associated double coset $Hx^{-1}yK$ is invariant. We claim that vice versa if we take a double coset $HzK$ we can individuate an orbit: just take $G.(H,zK)$. It is immediate to see this is well defined and the two assignments are inverse of each other.

Now we have to identify the stabilizer of a general element of the orbit $(xH,yK)$. This is by definition $\{g \in G : gxH=xH, gyK=yK\}$. This is constituted by $xHx^{-1}\cap yKy^{-1}$ which is isomorphic to $y^{-1}xHx^{-1}y \cap K$. Under the previous assignment $x^{-1}y$ corresponds to the representative of the double coset $HzK$. Now we orbit-stabilizer theorem lets us conclude.

I thought the isomorphism could be provided explicitly, like in the case of the second isomorphism theorem. If someone has a more elegant solution I will gladly consider it.

EDIT: after reconsidering this I realized that the above proof does not work for compact Lie groups. Indeed, the argument presents an equivariant bijection between the two $G$-sets but the target is not compact (it is a possibly infinite disjoint union). So the function is not necessarily continuous.

Does anyone know how to generalize the formula to the case where $G$ is a compact Lie group and $H,K$ are closed subgroups?

I suspect that we have to use the decomposition of the double coset $H\backslash G/K$ in orbit-type manifolds: this was the approach adopted by Freshbach in the paper "The Transfer and Compact Lie Groups" to generalize the double coset formula to the compact case. But I do not have much experience with this approach, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of approaching this is using a well-known $G$-equivariant isomorphism
$$
G/H\times X\cong G\times_H X
$$
where $X$ has a left $G$-action and the product on the left has the diagonal action. The isomorphism is given by sending the pair $(gH,x)$ to the equivalence class $[g,g^{-1}x]_H$.

Then working with the rhs, the stabilizer of the equivalence class $[1,xK]_H$ is $H\cap xKx^{-1}$ so its orbit is $G/H\cap xKx^{-1}$.

I think this gives an equivalent description.